# Bank acquisition effect

Tags: time-series, intervention-analysis, structural-change

Given that I have 4 banks (bank A, B, C and D) and the data (stock value) I have is from 1998 to present year.

At the year 2002, Bank A acquired Bank C.  At 2005, Bank A acquired Bank D. Until there is only 1 surviving Bank (A) at present. I want to test whether each merge was effective (in terms of Bank A) or not.

I consulted 2 professors and one recommended checking for structural change (and see change in level and volatility) while the other recommended intervention analysis. I'm torn to which one to use. Which do you think is best suited?

Comment: (1) Stock value is usually a poor metric.  Changes in stock price relative to an appropriate index will almost always be better.  (2) Given that intervention analysis uses *known* dates of events and structural change needs to *estimate* events, and you know the history of bank mergers, doesn't that answer your question?